# Reading data from a file into multiple arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that requires taking input from a file. I want to read the data such that the first column of the input file goes into the first array, 2nd column goes into 2nd array and so on.

The input file has 3 columns, of type string, int and double respectively.

So i need 3 arrays of type string, int and double. How can I read the data from the file so that each array gets it's respective data?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to implement your program while using an SQL solution like http://www.sqlite.org/ , it will be a much more reliable solution with a much better and simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in case you need it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> arr1;
vector<string> arr2;
vector<double> arr3;


int main()
{
    int i;
    string str;
    double d;
    ifstream fin("myfile.txt");
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            fin >> i >> str >> d;
            fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            arr1.push_back(i);
            arr2.push_back(str);
            arr3.push_back(d);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: really unsafe code, if the string in a given row in the file contains just a single whitespace this code will fail.

Comment: This is not good as you are checking for EOF too late. You need to verify the input before pushing back into the vector.

Comment: @CashCow: As I mentioned above, the input file has to be exact as it suppose to be. I can add more code to verify the values before pushing back to the vector, but I think it's overhead. About your sentence "checking EOF too late", could you explain more?

Comment: @user2485710: I think the input has to be clear. There should be no whitespace in the string. Of course the code will fail. In this case, have to read the whole line to a temporary string and extracting values from it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
while ( i < MAX_SIZE && myFile >> stringArray[i] >> intArray[i] >> doubleArray[i] )
  i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that you streamed correctly before pushing back into the vector, and for the sake of it, I am going to check ALL the values streamed in correctly before I push any into any of the vectors, so all the vectors will end up the same length.

```
std::vector< string > column1;
std::vector< int> column2;
std::vector< double > column3;

do
{
   // ifs is an open stream
    std::string temp1;
    int temp2;
    double temp3; 
    ifs >> temp1 >> temp2 >> temp3;
    if( ifs )
    {
        column1.push_back( temp1 );
        column2.push_back( temp2 );
        column3.push_back( temp3 );
    }
}
while( ifs );
```

This is only a "rough" example. It assumes the string is a single word. If it isn't, you need to know how to determine where that column ends, and read it appropriately.

It might be easier to create a struct for the 3 values, and to separate the reading from file to struct, and the moving from the struct to the vectors.

Obviously you will know the way the file is formatted. If you read a line into a string, then parse the string using the regex, that might be a better way to split it into the 3 component parts, in particular knowing where the "string" part ends. Perhaps your string is stored in the file within quotes.

Perhaps your columns are tab-delimited, in which case you read the string up to the tab character.

```
std::getline( ifs, temp1, '\t' );
```

If you are in control of the way your file is actually stored, this can be the simplest way to implement it.